# React-Query use query in context and set state of context and pass to component

Tags: reactjs, react-query

I have context in my react-app, I want to call a query in context and set the state value to an object from the api data. I have tried the following and I get the error, can't read property of undefined (4). So I know this could be because the data has not yet been returned and therefore I can't set the state to the object in the array, so how to get around this? Also how would I handle the status i.e loading etc in the component the context is passed to.

Another question is should I be calling the API in context, or should I call in the component and then set the context state in the component? is that better approach?

Code so far:

```
export const DataProvider: React.FunctionComponent = ({ children }) => {
 const getApi = async (): Promise<any> => {
    const response = await axios.get(`https://www.xxxxxx`).then(res => res.data);
    return response;
  }

  const { data: result, status, error, isFetching }: any = useQuery(['apiData'], () => getApi());

  const [myValue, setmyValue] = React.useState(result[4]); // this is causing the issue

  return (
    <DataContext.Provider value={{myValue, setmyValue, result}}>
      {children}
    </DataContext.Provider>
  );
};
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

react-query will give you `undefined` for `data` as long as `isLoading` is true. Since the initial value of `useState` is synchronous, this cannot really work.

if you really want to copy state from react-query, what you have to do is call  the `setMyValue` in `onSuccess` or in a `useEffect`:

```
const { data, status, error, isFetching } = useQuery(['apiData'], () => getApi());

React.useEffect(() => {
  if (data) {
    setMyValue(data)
  }
}, [data])
```

This would also make sure that background updates would be properly reflected in your state. However, you usually don't need to do this at all:

> I want to call a query in context and set the state value to an object from the api data.

I'm guessing that you think you want this because you want to have the data accessible anywhere in the app. The good news is that react-query is a state manager, and you can just do something like:

```
export const useApiData = useQuery(['apiData'], () => getApi());
```

and then you can call `const { data } = useApiData()` wherever you want in your app to retrieve the cached data. You will also get background updates for free.

I've written extensively about this topic in: [React Query as a State Manager](https://tkdodo.eu/blog/react-query-as-a-state-manager)

Comment: When would it be a good idea to use the useEffect?.

Comment: is this a good example?

server gives whether a form is notstarted or done, in UI we need to show a Progress indicator if it is being edited in Ui. So we store the fetched state (using setState or reducer) and when it is being edited set the same state to inProgress state.


1. query => { status: notStarted }
set the query state to local state using set state
2. status = notStarted
make some edits to the form
3. change the status to inProgress.